# Syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have this code:

```
 19   context 'overriding at fabricate time' do
 20     let(:fabricated_object) do
 21       Fabricate(
 22         "#{fabricator_name}_with_children", do
 23         string_field: 'new content',
 24         number_field: 10,
 25         nil_field: nil,
 26         placeholder: 'is not invoked',
 27         dynamic_field: { 'new dynamic content' }
 28       end)
 29     end
```

Fabricator:

```
  1 class Fabrication::Fabricator
  2 
  3   def self.build(name, overrides={}, &block)
  4     fail_if_initializing(name)
  5     schematic(name).build(overrides, &block)
  6   end
  7 
  8   def self.fabricate(name, overrides={}, &block)
  9     fail_if_initializing(name)
 10     schematic(name).fabricate(overrides, &block)
 11   end
 12 
 13   def self.to_attributes(name, overrides={}, &block)
 14     fail_if_initializing(name)
 15     schematic(name).to_attributes(overrides, &block)
 16   end
 17 
 18   def self.to_params(name, overrides={}, &block)
 19     fail_if_initializing(name)
 20     schematic(name).to_params(overrides, &block)
 21   end
 22 
 23   private
 24 
 25   def self.fail_if_initializing(name)
 26     raise Fabrication::MisplacedFabricateError.new(name) if Fabrication.manager.initializing?
 27   end
 28 
 29   def self.schematic(name)
 30     Fabrication::Support.find_definitions if Fabrication.manager.empty?
 31     Fabrication.manager[name] || raise(Fabrication::UnknownFabricatorError.new(name))
 32   end
 33 
 34 end
```

but I keep getting

```
integration_spec.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
        string_field: 'new content',
                     ^
/home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/fabrication_temp/spec/_seded/integration_spec.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/fabrication_temp/spec/_seded/integration_spec.rb:25: Can't assign to nil
/home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/fabrication_temp/spec/_seded/integration_spec.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
        placeholder: 'is not invoked'
                    ^
/home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/fabrication_temp/spec/_seded/integration_spec.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
...
```

How can I get around this?
I've tried formatting the hash in a number of ways but none worked.

Code used to work in this format (I am trying to move to expect):

```
  context 'overriding at fabricate time' do
    let(:fabricated_object) do
      Fabricate(
        "#{fabricator_name}_with_children",
        string_field: 'new content',
        number_field: 10,
        nil_field: nil,
        placeholder: 'is not invoked'
      ) do
        dynamic_field { 'new dynamic content' }
      end
    end
```

I also tried:

```
 19   context 'overriding at fabricate time' do
 20     let(:fabricated_object) do
 21       Fabricate(
 22         "#{fabricator_name}_with_children",
 23         { string_field: "new content",
 24         number_field: 10,
 25         nil_field: nil,
 26         placeholder: 'is not invoked',
 27         dynamic_field: { 'new dynamic content' }})
 28       
 29     end
```

but got

```
integration_spec.rb:23: odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError)
    { string_field: "new content",
```

Comment: Can you include all the matching `end`s for completeness sake? Since without them included that in itself is a SyntaxError. Also what Ruby version are you using?

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3-p194 or ruby 1.9.3-p448 (ruby 2.0 had other issues).  Def. not 1.8 :)

Comment: Looks like you have a typo there, close your bracket after `"#{fabricator_name}_with_children"` and remove the one at the end of the Fabricate block.

Comment: I tried that but getting `integration_spec.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
/home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/fabrication_temp/spec/_seded/integration_spec.rb:23: odd number lis
t for Hash` (currently also using `{}`'s - see code in Question.

Answer (score 1):

Try arranging that call to `Fabricate(...)` as follows:

```
  Fabricate("#{fabricator_name}_with_children".to_sym) do
    string_field  'new content'
    number_field  10 
    nil_field     nil
    placeholder   'is not invoked'
    dynamic_field { 'new dynamic content' }
  end
```

Edit: I've done some local console experimentation to make sure it should work. I'm assuming those values are defaults for a fabricator, e.g.

```
2.0.0p195 :014 > Fabricator(:x) do
2.0.0p195 :015 >   string_field  'new content'
2.0.0p195 :016?>   number_field  10 
2.0.0p195 :017?>   nil_field     nil
2.0.0p195 :018?>   placeholder   'is not invoked'
2.0.0p195 :019?>   dynamic_field { 'new dynamic content' }
2.0.0p195 :020?> end
```

I can fabricate an instance ok--

```
2.0.0p195 :032 > Fabricate(:x)
 => #<X:0x98c32c4 @string_field="new content", @number_field=10, @nil_field=nil, @placeholder="is not invoked", @dynamic_field="new dynamic content">
```

I can pass a block like above--

```
2.0.0p195 :055 > Fabricate(:x) do
2.0.0p195 :056 >   string_field  'alternate content'
2.0.0p195 :057?>   number_field  999
2.0.0p195 :058?>   nil_field     nil
2.0.0p195 :059?>   placeholder   'changed'
2.0.0p195 :060?>   dynamic_field { 'different dynamic content' }
2.0.0p195 :061?> end 
 => #<X:0x948eff0 @string_field="alternate content", @number_field=999, @nil_field=nil, @placeholder="changed", @dynamic_field="different dynamic content">
```

Or use a mixed mode with params/block:

```
2.0.0p195 :062 > Fabricate(:x, string_field: 'new content', number_field: 37, nil_field: nil, placeholder: 'blah') do
2.0.0p195 :063 >       dynamic_field { 'new dynamic content' }
2.0.0p195 :064?>   end 
 => #<X:0x92c4e54 @string_field="new content", @number_field=37, @nil_field=nil, @placeholder="blah", @dynamic_field="new dynamic content">
```

At this stage I'd guess the problem is an unclosed block somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I get `integration_spec.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting kDO or '{' or
 '(' (SyntaxError)
        number_field 10,
                       ^
/home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/code/ruby/fabrication_temp/spec/_seded/integration_spec.rb:26: syntax error, 
unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
        placeholder 'is not invoked'
`

Comment: What does your Fabricator class look like?

Comment: Sorry, I meant your own Fabricator (e.g. the Fabricator class you define like I did in the second code block above). I don't think that's your issue anyway. Try putting in place a Fabricate() block exactly like I have above, I noticed you had extra colons in your block (e.g. you are using a hash-like syntax in the function body)

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing 2.0.0-specific there.

Comment: hmmm, I'm still getting the `integration_spec.rb:23: odd number list for Hash
        { string_field: "new content",
` though

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this:

```
 21       Fabricate(
 22         "#{fabricator_name}_with_children", do
 23         # ...
 28       end)
```

Be more like:

```
 21       Fabricate(
 22         "#{fabricator_name}_with_children") do
 23         # ...
 28       end
```

As in, with the closing parenthesis before the do, rather than (incorrectly) wrapping it?

Another possible alternative, in the event it still spits out an error, to make sure that operator precedence is applied correctly:

```
 21       Fabricate(
 22         "#{fabricator_name}_with_children") {
 23         # ...
 28       }
```

---

Yet another option, seeing that the contents of that thing looks like a hash rather than a block:

```
 21       Fabricate(
 22         "#{fabricator_name}_with_children", {
 23         # ...
 28       })
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and got: integration_spec.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
        string_field: "new content",

Comment: I tried the 2nd and got integration_spec.rb:23: odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError)
        { string_field: "new content",

Comment: You're probably on the right track, then. Replace all those nested do end blocks with the tighter { } syntax and see what comes out. (Imho, the error might occur before the code you posted.)

Comment: I added a third suggestion.